# passing javascript options in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ruby gem [bootstrap-datepicker-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails) in my Rails-4 application, to draw a form for taking `from_date` and `till_date` as input as following. The beauty of this code is no javascript is needed as that in encoded in this gem's code.

```
<div class=" input-daterange" id="datepicker" data-provide='datepicker'>
  <label>From Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from_date" id="from_date">

  <label>Till Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="till_date" id="till_date">
</div>
```

By default it takes format as “mm/dd/yyyy”, I want to change it to “yyyy-dd-mm”, Is it possible to do this by passing this in html options only and not using any javascript for it. I tried following and some other permutations of these, but of-course they didn't work.

```
<div class=" input-daterange" id="datepicker" data-provide='datepicker' options='format:"yyyy-mm-dd"'>

<div class="row input-daterange" id="datepicker" data-provide='datepicker' format="yyyy-mm-dd" >
```

Please let me know if this is possible to do and how.

Comment: Did you try : data-format = 'yyyy-mm-dd' :-                                                               <div class=" input-daterange" id="datepicker" data-provide='datepicker' data-format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs suggest you do it like this:

```
<input class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration

Note that the attribute goes on the input element and is called data-date-format

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work just like this, but like - `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="till_date" id="till_date" data-provide='datepicker' data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" >
`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the right name of the html attribute, try :

`data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd"`

Source : documentation